# How to print the following with php[preferred] or javaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

So i was asked the following question in an interview. I was able to print the whole xxx thing. but it was not diagonal like the below one. I think it meant to have spaces prints through a loop. Can Someone please help me with this.

How to print the following using php or javascript?? Php would be preferred.

```
     xx
    xxxx
   xxxxxx
  xxxxxxxx
 xxxxxxxxxx
```

what i was able to get was

```
xx
xxxx
xxxxxx
xxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
```

through php for loop.

Comment: If you checked 'view source' in the browser it would probably render correctly. When parsed, HTML won't render spaces, so you need to use `&nbsp`

Comment: Show us what you have tried and where in specific you think the problem is so that you can ask an actual specific question instead of your current `canihazcode` request

Comment: Use `&nbsp;` instead of a space ` ` or use a `<pre>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution in Javascript:

```js
function tree(base) {
    var i = base,
        j;
    document.write('<pre>');

    while (i--) {
        j = i;
        while (j--) {
            document.write('&nbsp;');
        }
        j = base * 2 - i * 2;
        while (j--) {
            document.write('X');
        }
        document.write('<br>');
    }
    document.write('</pre>');
}

tree(5);
tree(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple example

```
<?php

    $char       = "x";
    $multiplier = 2;
    $repeat     = 5;

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $repeat; $i++) {

        $output = null;

        for ($j = 1; $j <= $multiplier*$i; $j++) {

            $output .= $char;

        }

        $nbsp = null;

        for ($k = 1; $k <= ($repeat-$i)*$multiplier; $k++) {

            $nbsp .= "&nbsp;";

        }

        echo $nbsp . $output . "<br/>";

    }

?>
```